# Change html id with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Practice</title>
<script src="my.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Practice Page</h1>

<p>click on ^ to show am
<code class="js">alert()</code>.</p>

<p id="hoverable">Put your mouse here to make every paragraph red <code class="html">&lt;p&gt;</code> get the class
<code class="h">highlighted</code></p>
```

I have imported a jquery file already with another  which isn't included here, and my current javascript code is as follows:

```
head = function() {
  alert("I'm a heading");
}

redtext=function(){
    $('hoverable').attr("#hoverable","#highlighted");

}
setup = function() {
  jQuery('h1').click(head);
  jQuery('p').mouseover(red);    

}
jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

With my css code being:

```
.highlighted {
  color: red;
}
```

I'm trying to make it so when ever i highlight over the hoverable id, all the paragraphs turn red, so the new id would be highlighted for all the paragraphs,  I tried changing the id, but i can't seem to get it to work

Comment: `$('#hoverable').on('mouseenter', function() { $('body *').addClass('highlighted') })`. Please note that this is jQuery (which is a library written in and for Javascript, but it is not Javascript).

Comment: So would i put that into my colour function, and then call it from my setup? Or directly input that into my ready function

Comment: In your setup function.

Answer (score 1):

To select an element by ID, use '#', which is missing in your code.

Change following line from your color function-

```
$('hoverable').attr("#hoverable","#highlighted");
```

to the following if highlighted is an ID -

```
$('#hoverable').attr("id","highlighted");
```

If highlighted is a class,

```
$('#hoverable').attr("class","highlighted");
```

Comment: `highlighted` is a class in his code, not an id.

Comment: @Monicka Thanks so much! That made the hoverable change into highlighted, if i wanted to make the paragraphs change as well when we mouseover hoverable, would i do the same thing and add a p setting? or add a new function, cause I don't want it to be red when i hover over the "clicking this paragraph" but red when we hover the 2nd paragraph

Comment: @Monicka don't use `attr` to add a class as it will replace all existing classes on the element. Use `$(selector).addClass('classname')`.

Comment: color=function(){
    $('#hoverable').attr("class","highlighted");
    $('p').addClass('hoverable)

or

color=function(){
    $('#hoverable').addClass('highlighted');
    $('p').addClass('highlighted');

?

Comment: Yes @connexo is right. When you have more than one paragraphs, use an ID tag instead of the element. For example in you case - you can say - jQuery('#hoverable').mouseover(color);